# Why no constant $C$ when integrating $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$?

Tags: integration

Why is there no constant $C$ added when integrating from $0$ to $x$ in $$ \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$$

Is this the only case when $C$ can be omitted?

Comment: This is a definite integral. Definite integrals never have $C$ (indefinite integrals always have it).

Comment: $ \int_{0}^{0}f(t)dt=0$ hense $C=0$

Answer (score 2):

if you assume the integral of function f(t) is g(t)+C, so
$$\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=[g(x)+C]-[g(0)+C]=g(x)-g(0)$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}$In calculus, the integral sign is used to denote two substantially distinct concepts, antidifferentiation and integration (a.k.a. *indefinite integration* and *definite integration*), that turn out to be closely related (for the class of continuous functions) by the fundamental theorems.

Let $I = [a, b]$ be a closed, bounded interval of real numbers.

- If $f$ is a *derivative* on $I$, i.e., if there exists a function $F$ on $I$ such that $F' = f$,[1] then we write
  $$
  \int f(t)\, dt = F(t) + C
  $$
  to signify that the general antiderivative of $f$ on $I$ is $F$ plus a constant.[2]
- If $f$ is (Riemann) *integrable* on $I$, i.e., if $f$ is bounded, and the lower and upper sums of $f$ with respect to a partition $P$ of $I$ can be made arbitrarily close,[3] then
  $$
  \int_{a}^{b} f(t)\, dt
  $$
  denotes the least upper bound of the lower sums of $f$ on $I$, which by hypothesis is equal to the greatest lower bound of the upper sums of $f$ on $I$.

Clearly these usages of the integral sign are logically distinct. In fact, they apply to slightly different classes of function; not every derivative is Riemann integrable, and not every integrable function is a derivative.

In many elementary calculus courses, the "common ground" between these usages is to assume $f$ is *continuous* on $I$. Every continuous function turns out to be both a derivative and to be Riemann integrable, and one fundamental theorem of calculus asserts that
$$
F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t)\, dt
$$
is an antiderivative of $f$ on $[a, b]$. Moreover, if $G$ is an arbitrary antiderivative of $f$ on $[a, b]$, the other fundamental theorem of calculus asserts
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(t)\, dt = G(t)\Big|_{t=a}^{t=b} = G(b) - G(a).
$$
That is, in the appropriate setting we may regard the symbol
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(t)\, dt
$$
as *either* a definite integral (in which case there is no "$+C$"), or as the difference between two values of an antiderivative of $f$ (in which case the "$+C$"s cancel), and these interpretations agree.

Finally, a coda to your question: If you encounter an integral sign with limits (even if one or both limits are "variables"), such as
$$
\int_{0}^{x} f(t)\, dt,
$$
context dictates definite integration.

---

**Notes**:

1. To split hairs, $F' = f$ on $[a, b]$ means: There exists an open interval $(c, d) \supset [a, b]$ and a differentiable function $F$ on $(c, d)$ such that $F'(t) = f(t)$ for all $t$ in $[a, b]$.
2. Formally, if $G' = f$ on $I$, there exists a real number $C$ such that $G(t) = F(t) + C$ for all $t$ in $I$.
3. Precisely, for every $\eps > 0$, there exists a partition $P$ of $[a, b]$ such that
   $$
   U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \eps.
   $$

Answer (score 0):

If You write $\int f(t)dt=F(x)+C$ for the indefinite integral You actually mean the set of all antiderivatives:

$\int f(t)dt=\{F:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}:F´=f\}$.
Since two functions $F_1$ and $F_2$ in this set satisfy $(F_1-F_2)´\equiv 0$ they can only differ by a constant $C\in \mathbb{R}$. So

$\int f(t)dt=\{F+C:C\in\mathbb{R}\}$ where $F´=f$

This is why one writes ( a bit sloppy)$\int f(t)dt=F(x)+C$.

The link between this indefinite integral and the limits of the Riemann sums (the definite integrals) is then given by the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$\int_a^b f(t)dt=F(a)-F(b)$ for some $F\in \int f(t)dt$.

Comment: You should impose that $D$ is connected.

Comment: and it should be open .